# Bottom nav bar android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, bottomnavigationview

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomnav">

    </FrameLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomnav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Whenever i try to add bottom navigation bar the whole activity goes blank

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to display buttons in the Bottom Navigation Bar, you need to add `app:menu` to `BottomNavigationView`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomnav">
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomnav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Under **res/menu**, create a **bottom_nav_menu.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/main" android:title="Main" />
    <item android:id="@+id/secondary" android:title="Secondary" />
</menu>
```

Then you should see 2 buttons in your Bottom Navigation Bar.

---

The above should work fine on a **Physical Android Device**. If you are not able to preview the Bottom Navigation Bar in **Design** view of Android Studio, please check if your **build.gradle** has the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
```

You can either downgrade it to:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

or upgrade it to:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
```